# Can you render multiple views/same layout from one controller action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, layout, view, render

**Important context:**

I'm building a progressive web app. As an example, the `new` action might have a series of steps, where each step has a clear, discrete, page dedicated to JUST that step:

1. Find what you want to order (some helpful guidelines)
2. Bring it to the check out point (some helpful guidelines)
3. Check out with it (some helpful guidelines)
4. Lock the door on your way out

All the pages share a single layout with some generic features (e.g., a next/back button on each step). The idea is that a page view looks something like this:

```
<div id="step-1">
<div id="step-2" class="hidden">
<div id="step-3" class="hidden">
<div id="step-4" class="hidden">
```

Where there are next/back buttons in each step with javascript that hides/unhides other pages. User never really has to submit anything, it's really just about guiding the user through a series of steps without having to redirect them to multiple controller actions (and separate view files) which increases loading time.

I'm trying to figure out the strategy to organize my view code. What makes the most sense to me is something like this

```
views
  layouts
    progressive_layout.html.erb
  orders
    new
      step_1.html.erb
      step_2.html.erb
      step_3.html.erb
      step_4.html.erb
```

The above reads super clean to me, and I feel like it would be easiest to manage, know where to edit. For additional context, before, I had a single file, and in the controller, I had basically a ridiculous quantity of instance variables defining the various pieces of content in the view files. That does NOT work.

The problem, is that with a single action, how do I actually get this to render? Obviously I can't do the below (since `render` can only be called once per action):

```
def new
  4.times do |i|
    render "orders/new/step_#{i}", layout: "progressive_layout"
  end
end
```

The only real way would be to push the multiple times into the `progressive_layout`

```
<% 4.times do |i| %>
   <!-- generic content -->
   <%= render "orders/new/step_#{i}" %> <!-- partialize the unique content -->
   <!-- generic content -->
<% end %>
```

But this is still very clunky, because `progressive_layout` is once again used in other actions where there may be more/less than 4 steps. Essentially I want to find a really clean way of allowing a single action to build X number of "layout-unique content" pairs.

Is this possible?

If not, I'm thinking what I may have to do then is to have the controller only render the first step, and the subsequent next button submit AJAX to another controller action that pulls the right next step to render.

Comment: No no no. Remove client layer from server. Why do people still use templates??? The client can build it's self completely user side. Off load all that computation away from your server.

Comment: Would [Wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) do what you need?

Comment: @Darkrum can you please provide an example answer?

Comment: @jljohnstone thanks for the tip! Checked it out! From what I can tell, each of wicked's steps still is a new request right? in my case, the steps are like... superficial, they're just text instructions, so I just want the JS to hide/show each step as opposed to actually having a new request

Answer (score 0):

Rails not allows render multiple times.

```
views
  layouts
    progressive_layout.html.erb
  orders
    new
      step.html.erb
      _step_1.html.erb
      _step_2.html.erb
      _step_3.html.erb
      _step_4.html.erb


#controller
render "orders/new/step", layout: "progressive_layout"


# In step.html.erb
<% 4.times do |i| %>
   <!-- generic content -->
   <%= render "step_#{i}" %> <!-- partialize the unique content -->
   <!-- generic content -->
<% end %>
```

## Updated

You can pass params from outside and check in partials. [Doc local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)

```
# In step.html.erb
<%= render partial: "step_#{i}", locals: {hidden: true} %>

# In _step_1.html.erb
 <div class="<%= hidden ? 'hidden': '' %>">
```

Comment: the problem is that this will render the layout once around 4 times of step content. I need to have the layout around EACH step of content

Comment: @james why do you want to load layout 4 times ? or you have numbered layouts `layout: "progressive_layout_#{1}"` ?

Comment: each step has the exact same layout. but there are some elements that depend on the step, so for example, the first step has the `<div id="back" class="hidden">` whereas step 2 doesn't have class hidden, so I render the layout individually for each step to account for minor differences

Comment: hmmm.... unless there's a way to yield those minor differences, but then I'm yielding from the layout to a set of rendered files. but that actually should work with `yield, flush: true` right?